# Is there a specific name for matrices that are the sum of an antisymmetric matrix and a diagonal matrix

Tags: matrices, terminology

Sorry for the potential duplicate but it seems difficult to get reliable search results based on the words "matrix","antisymmetric","diagonal" for this problem.

I study a physical phenomenon which involves matrices of the form

\begin{bmatrix}a & -b\\b& a\end{bmatrix}

Of course, such a matrix could be defined as the sum of a diagonal matrix \begin{bmatrix}a & 0\\0 & a\end{bmatrix} and of an antisymmetrix matrix 
\begin{bmatrix}0 & -b\\b& 0\end{bmatrix}
but is there a name for such matrices, that are close to antisymmetric ones, except for the nonzero diagonal terms ?

Comment: For $2 \times 2$ case that you mention it can be called "Real Jordan block". See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Real_matrices

Comment: @Zeekless, That is a very interesting proposal ! I would have preferred a more general definition, but this is again very good to know. Thanks :)

Comment: You can also notice that these kind of matrices are very similar to complex numbers.. the scalar part is the real part while the antisymmetric part is the imaginary part!

Comment: @Fabrizio it is not mentioned in the question, but those matrices arise from a real/imaginay parts split of otherwise complex numbers, good call